# Не получается опубликовать пустой Asp.Net MVC проект на хостинге reg.ru

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, хостинг, hosting

создаю пустой проект MVC, чтобы протестировать хостинг
В панели настроено всё правильно (как я думаю). Версияя .net фреймворка хостинга- 4.7, у приложения - 4.6.1
После публикации на reg.ru получаю ошибку 500. Делаю всё стандартно согласно инструкциям в интернете
Проблем не должно быть - на 1gb всё работало. Видимо нужны какие-то настройки в web.config или ещё где-то
В какую сторону копать?

Comment: "получаю ошибку 500" - смотрите по логам в чем заключается ошибка.

Comment: лог в браузере? сейчас Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Нужен серверный лог. Браузер вам только говорит, что "что-то на сервере пошло не так".

Comment: как мне получить серверные логи?

Comment: Пересоздайте новый проект, что-то в проекте вы сделали не так.

Comment: да, проект сломался. сейчас всё ок. спасибо ответившим!